# Windows validate checksum

Tags: windows, checksum, certutil

I am trying to validate the checksum for a Windows [Citrix executable](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/workspace-app/windows/workspace-app-for-windows-latest.html).
The checksum that is provided is 64 char long.
I have found instructions to validate a checksum by running this in PowerShell:

```
certutil.exe -hashfile CitrixWorkspaceApp.exe md5
```

This produces a hash that is shorter than what I need. I tried different algorithm names, but I still cannot match the posted checksum. Since this is the first time I try this, my assumption is that I am doing something wrong. Perhaps I should specify a different algorithm (not "md5" or "sha1") - but which checksum algorithm generates a 64-char value?

Comment: Try SHA-256 as that is specified for the [Citrix Workspace app 2002 Desktop Lock](https://www.citrix.com/en-gb/downloads/workspace-app/additional-client-software/workspace-app-desktop-lock-Latest2.html) program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The checksum that is provided is 64 char long. I have found instructions to validate a checksum by running this in PowerShell:
>
> `certutil.exe -hashfile CitrixWorkspaceApp.exe md5`

**MD5 hashes are never 64 characters long.**  If the checksum is a 64 character string, then it was not calculated, using the MD5 hashing algorithm.

> Since this is the first time I try this, my assumption is that I am doing something wrong. Perhaps I should specify a different algorithm (not "md5" or "sha1") - but which checksum algorithm generates a 64-char value?

`SHA1` nor `MD5` would be applicable in this case.  `SHA256` produces a 64-character string.  What should work is the following command:

```
certutil -hashfile CitrixWorkspaceApp.exe SHA256
```